# Need to remove the comma in a number in my dynamic generated classic asp site

Tags: sql, string, asp-classic

I have an old website which uses classic asp.  I have a problem in that whenever I display a price, if it is above £1000.00 it displays with a comma, ie £1,000.00.

How do I force it to remove or not use the comma?

My connection script is:

```
<% 
                        Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")' initialize connection
                        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")' initialize record set
                        adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("stockdetails.mdb")

                        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM StockDetails WHERE ID=" &trim(pro_type)&""
                        rs.open strSQL,adoCon,1,1  'open record set
                        if not rs.eof then

                        manufacturerid=rs("ManufacturerID")
                        manufacturer=rs("Manufacturer")
                        price=FormatNumber(rs("Price") ,2)


                        else
                        response.End()end if

                        rs.close
                        adoCon.close
                    %>
```

The code used to pull the price onto the page is:

```
<% = price %>
```

Even if I change all the price fields in the database to display without the comma, they still show on the site with one.

How do I get rid of it?

Many thanks in advance.

Ian

Comment: your solution is ok but you will lose the functionality that forces the display of two decimal digits only.

Comment: @GMB they only need to use `FormatNumber()` when they want to display the value, during calculations you should steer clear of any string formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The comma does not come from database. It is placed here by the « FormatNumber » function that you invoke after data is recovered from database :

```
price=FormatNumber(rs("Price") ,2)
```

If you need no formatting at all, you can simply remove the call to FormatNumber :

```
price=rs("Price")
```

But if you want to keep the control over the number of digits, the you do need FormatNumber. By default FormatNumber relies on regional settings of your computer : in your use case, this lead to a comma being used as thousand separator. This can be changed by passing more arguments to the function :

```
price=FormatNumber(rs("Price") ,2,,,0)
```

See [the FormatNumber docs](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatnumber.asp).

Comment: Actually, the best approach is to not format the number in the first place.

Comment: I still need formatting in this case, so this answers helps me the best. Without formatting, I have a bizzare situation of two identical numbers, one from a read .csv file and another from SQL DB, but doesn't recognise it in an if check. So I need to format it first.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the answer as soon as I pressed the Submit button...

So this is part of the connection script:

```
price=FormatNumber(rs("Price") ,2)
```

All I did was change the code to:

```
price=rs("Price")
```

And it works perfectly.

D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Personnly I store "monies" value as a number then just times it by 100 when I need to display it. I believe stripe the payment processing company does the same thing. This saves formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Since I need to format my number but a comma was included in the formatnumber() result.

I was able to remove the comma using the following approach:

```
price=FormatNumber(rs("Price") ,2,,,0)
```

This works perfect for me.